# Editor with a live preview/rendering of MoinMoin Wiki (.moin) files

Tags: text-editor, wysiwyg, moinmoin

I am looking for an editor which can render/preview my `.moin` files - pretty much the same way Atom is capable of rendering Markdown files (it doesn't have to be WYSIWYG). I'd use Atom but it doesn't seem to have a MoinMoin-dedicated rendering package.

I am interested in editors running on OS X or FreeBSD. A convenient web-based editor suits me fine as well.